# Defining the dimension of a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, affine-geometry

In Stephen Boyd's optimization book, it says

> "We define the dimension of an affine set C as the dimension of the
>   subspace V = C−x0,where x0 is any element of C"

I have two questions regarding this:

1. Why do we need to introduce the subspace to define the dimension of the affine set ?
2. Based on my understanding, I am guessing the subspace is a subset which is a vector space and is closed under linear combinations [[link]](http://homepages.rpi.edu/~mitchj/handouts/affine/)

So the subspace is also an affine set. This leads to a circular argument for defining the dimension of an affine set. I would appreciate some clarity regarding the above points.

Comment: Either this is a typo or you are quoting the definition incorrectly: The set V that you wrote is not a linear subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of a linear subspace is well-defined (refer to any linear algebra text); as you noted it is a subset of a vector space that is itself a vector space (closed under linear combinations).

Boyd is defining the dimension of an affine set by producing a related set $C-x_0$ that happens to be a linear subspace, and then referring to the established definition of dimension for linear subspaces. There is no circular argument here.

The set $C-\{x_0\}$ is *not* a subset of $C$; geometrically, it is shifting/translating the affine space until it touches the origin.

Comment: So am I write in understanding that if an affine set touches the origin, it becomes a linear set ?